# How to use OR Condition in selenium findElements() method for any selector?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to get all WebElement information having class name "act" or "dact"

I am using below line of code to get all class information for "act". Can any one help me to use OR condition in class name?

`List<WebElement> nL2 = driver.findElements(By.className("act"));`

Something similar to this; so that I don't have to write two separate  line for each class.

`//this is not working`

`List<WebElement> nL2 = driver.findElements(By.className("act | dact"));`

Thanks!

Comment: This is not XPath. This is XPath `//WebElement[@class[contains(concat(' ',.,' '),' act ') or contains(concat(' ',.,' '),' dact ')]]`

Comment: @Alejandro, my mistake. Modified my Question. actually I want to use OR condition in fineElements() method using any selectors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you just combine the two lists?

```
List<WebElement> act = driver.findElements(By.className("act"));
List<WebElement> dact = driver.findElements(By.className("dact"));
List<WebElement> all = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
all.addAll(act);
all.addAll(dact);
```

Alternatively, you could use an xpath locator as suggested by @Alejandro

```
List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='act' or @class='dact']"));
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, i din't think of doing this way.

Comment: Can we also use `By.className("X or Y");` or this OR condition is only applicable to XPath?

Comment: `className` takes a single class name.

Comment: Is there any other method which accept more than one like XPath??

Comment: +1 For conditional xpath. That was the best way to test generically, in my instance due to the fact that our site had multiple versions of the same page/button that did the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is really old but probably the easiest way to do this is to use a CSS selector like

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".act, .dact"));
```

You should prefer CSS selectors to XPath because the browser support is better and they are more performant (and I think they are easier to learn/understand). CSS selectors can do everything `By.className()` can plus a whole lot more. They are very powerful and very useful.

Some CSS selector references to get you started.

[W3C CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[Sauce Labs CSS Selector Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

Comment: This is by far the superior solution in modern times.