# Is there a C# equivalent for @FindAll in Java

Tags: c#, selenium, pageobjects

Java's @FindAll allows the user to match at least one of the given criteria e.g.

```
@FindAll({
    @FindBy(className = "class1")
    @FindBy(className = "class2")
})
private List<WebElement> elementsWithEither_class1ORclass2
```

I would like to know if there's a C# implementation of this or how I could replicate it. I am using Selenium Webdriver to access the elements.

It is different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362208/how-to-use-or-condition-in-selenium-findelements-method-for-any-selector) questions as I am required to use the POM

Comment: I see `WebElement` which makes me think you mean HTML classes, but you haven't mentioned what technology you're working with to access the page. It doesn't look like HtmlAgilityPack. Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use OR Condition in selenium findElements() method for any selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362208/how-to-use-or-condition-in-selenium-findelements-method-for-any-selector)

Comment: https://www.swtestacademy.com/page-object-model-c/  this may give some idea.

Comment: For your information pagefactory is deprecated from c#

Comment: If pagefactory is deprecated, what would you use to implement page objects?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is xPath with `Class or Class`.

Use the following in your page object

```
/// <summary>
/// The elements with class1 or class2
/// </summary>
[FindsBy(How = How.xPath, Using = "//*[@class='class1' or @class='class2']")]
[CacheLookup]
public IList<IWebElement> Class1Class2Elements{ get; set; }
```